# How to assign a GSP variable in a Grails template body()?

Tags: templates, grails, gsp

In my Grails 1.3.7 app, I'd like to use a template to factor out surrounding HTML from views.  But, GSP variable assignment isn't working in the contained body().  How can I do something like the following?

_*aTemplate.gsp:*

```
<div class="example">
    <% out <<  body() %>
</div>
```

*aView.gsp:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>
<body>
    <g:set var="foo" value="${42}"/>
    <% assert foo == 42 : foo %>

    <tmpl:/aTemplate>
        <g:set var="bar" value="${6}"/>
        <% assert bar == 6 : bar %>
    </tmpl:/aTemplate>
</body>
</html>
```

The assignment of `bar` doesn't work: the `bar` assertion fails, when I get http://localhost:8080/myApp/aView.gsp

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException:
 Error executing tag<g:render>: Assertion failed:
(bar == 6). Values: bar = null
 at /Users/jbeutel/proj/grailsSandboxes/myApp/grails-app/views/aView.gsp:13
```

How can I make the template body() work as normal?

Alternatively, is there some other way I could factor out surrounding HTML while keeping it balanced?  My use case isn't at the top level, so I haven't tried using layouts.  The variable assignment works if I use a TagLib closure instead of a template file, but I don't want to put a lot of HTML into a closure, so I would need to put unbalanced HTML into template files anyway (i.e., separate templates before and after the body).  Is there a better way?

Comment: How far into using layouts have you looked? It seems to me like they may be a bit more conducive to solving your problem. I haven't used them in the situation you're describing (so I'm not confident enough to post an actual answer), but [`<g:applyLayout/>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/applyLayout.html) seems like it might offer some tasty functionality. If nothing else, it may not suffer from the same behavior you're observing if used in a similar manner (but again, I don't know for sure). Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks!  That inline layout worked.  I changed `<% out << body() %>` to `<g:layoutBody />`, moved `view/_aTemplate.gsp` to `layouts/aLayout.gsp`, and called it with `<g:applyLayout name="aLayout">`.  Code in both the layout and body seems to be working; I didn't need to provide a parameter map for the layout, either.

Comment: But, I hit a problem with it:  the layout gets only the model from the controller.  I don't see a way for aView.gsp to pass in anything besides pageProperty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables from your .gsp into shared templates that it can then consider as follows.  I do this to hide a 'login' link in my common header if they are on the login.gsp page

```
<g:render template="/layouts/header" model="['hidelogin':true]"/>
```

then in the _header.gsp

```
<g:if test="${!hidelogin}">
    //show your login link
</g:if>
```